# Topological spaces with countable open set difference

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, first-countable

My question is regarding the existance of "countably close" open sets to those of a parotopological group (or any group equipped with a topology).

Consider a group $G$ equipped with a certain topology $\tau$ making the space $G_{\tau}$.

Is there another topology $\tau'$ on $G$ making the space $G_{\tau'}$ such that the difference between each open set $U\subseteq G_{\tau'}$ and some open set $V\subseteq G_{\tau}$ is countable $|U\setminus V|\leq\aleph_{0}$

I tried to find a justification for the existance of $G_{\tau'}$ by showing that the three axioms of a topology are preserved.

A Simple example is that of the Euclidean (real) line $\mathbb{R}$
and the Sorgenfrey line $\mathbb{S}$
in which each open set $[a,b)$
has a coressponding $(a,b)$
so that their difference is just one element.

Comment: Like for example $\tau'=\tau$? Also what exactly "group equiped with topology" is? As in topological group?

Comment: @freakish Just another way of saying "topological space on a group" because topological groups are defined to also preserve continuity of the group operation $\cdot: G\times G\rightarrow G$ and the inverse $^{-1}: G\rightarrow G$

Comment: So group structure is irrelevant? It's simply topological space. Also discrete $\tau'$ will always work.

Comment: @freakish yes a discrete set works, sorry I wanted to mention those $\tau'$ so that for any neighbourhood of the identity $U$ there is a countable subset $F$ so that $UF=G$, in case of an uncountable group $G$ such condition won't hold for discrete topologies.

Comment: @freakish actually the condition that $|U\setminus V|\leq\aleph_{0}$ for each $U\subset G_{\tau}$ and for each $U\subset G_{\tau'}$ also works..